# Is it possible to intercept writes to a file using Node?

Tags: node.js, fs, intercept

I have a third-party service that writes to a dozen or so log files. I would like to listen to all writes to these log files and redirect them to my application instead of having the data actually written to the files.

Is there such a thing as a writeListener/writeInterceptor that I can use to redirect the writes to these log files to my application?

This is a simplification but my intention is basically to write `tail -f *` as a Node application, that does stuff conditionally based off of what it reads in.

**Edit:**

Best idea that I can come up with is replacing the original file with a symlink to a corresponding `/dev/filename` and then listening to `/dev/filename` with Node.

Second best idea is using the OS's `tail` and reading in stdout.

Neither of these ideas are particularly cross-platform and the first idea involves deleting the existing files.

Comment: Your first idea is the closest I can think of.  Instead of creating a symlink, though, just rename the original files and create a new file with the old name.  When the application is closed, delete the files you created and rename the original files to use their original names.

Comment: Or if you have control over the service that writes the data, you can redirect its output.

Comment: @c1moore Yeah, the idea behind using fake devices was so that the output wouldn't be saved to the files. With just regular files can you think of a way to meet that requirement? I don't have control over the service without things getting hacky.

Comment: It's becoming less important that I prevent writing to the original files the more I think about it. It's more of just a feasibility question at this point.

Comment: I would highly doubt that Node is low level enough to do anything quite like what you're asking, especially with your cross-platform requirement.

Comment: Yeah, it seems that way. I appreciate your help :)